# How to post a request with JSON:API compliant data to json server?

Tags: reactjs, axios, json-api

I am trying out a simple project wherein I want to post JSON:API compliant data to json-server.
But whenever I am trying to post, only the id is being saved and the data is not persisted.

The db.json file looks like this initially.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "posts",
      "id": "1",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "First post",
        "content": "This is my first post"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "posts",
      "id": "2",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Second post",
        "content": "This is my second post"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Whenever I run the json-server this data is accessible on **http://localhost:4000/data**

Below is the simple code I have written in jsx for posting another post upon click of Create Post button.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function PostAPI() {
  const postData = {
    "data" : {
      type: "posts",
      attributes: {
        title: "Third Post",
        content: "Trying Out!"
      }
    }
  }
  const handlePost = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:4000/data',
        postData,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json'
          }
        }
      );
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handlePost}>Create Post</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default PostAPI;
```

But whenever I click on createPost a randomly generated id is only being saved like below.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "posts",
      "id": "1",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "First post",
        "content": "This is my first post"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "posts",
      "id": "2",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Second post",
        "content": "This is my second post"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "4s1qw0u"
    }
  ]
}
```

What is going wrong?
Please help!

Comment: my guess is that you don't need to wrap your postdata in a data attribute. Try this instead

`const postData = {type: "posts", attributes: {title: "Third Post",content: "Trying Out!"} }`

Comment: And the server side code?

Comment: @HenriDev [It’s required by JSON:API.](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-top-level)

Answer (score 0):

The data you are sending is not a valid JSON:API document for creating resources. For create requests the `data` member must be a single JSON:API resource object:

> **Creating Resources**
>
> A resource can be created by sending a POST request to a URL that represents a collection of resources. The request MUST include a single resource object as primary data.
>
> https://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-creating

Creating multiple resources in a single request is not supported by the base spec. If you have that requirement, you may want to look into the [Atomic Operations extension](https://jsonapi.org/ext/atomic/).